# Enforce compiler error when naming a parameter of a java method when called from scala

Tags: scala, maven, intellij-idea

I have a java class like the following:

```
public class Foo {
  public void foo(boolean flag) {}
}
```

And a scala class like the following:

```
class Bar {
  def bar(): Unit = {
    val foo = new Foo()
    foo.foo(flag = true)
  }
}
```

This causes a compiler error to be displayed inside intellij (as it should, since there are no parameter names stored in java classes), but when building from the command line with maven, there is no compiler error. Is there a setting to cause this to be an error in the maven build?

Comment: Q: A Java compile error causes the corresponding Maven task to fail, doesn't it?

Comment: No, it's not a java compiler error. There is nothing wrong in the java phase because it's just compiling the java files. The problem is that the scala phase should recognize that there is an attempt to name a parameter of a class that does not have parameter names in it and throw an error as a result. However, the scala phase in maven simply succeeds even though it couldn't possibly validate the correctness of the name of the parameter.

Comment: Is it possible Maven is not compiling the Scala classes at all? Are they in `src/main/scala`? Are you using `scala-maven-plugin` or the old `maven-scala-plugin`?